# Pyqt5 message box

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to display a table with 2 columns and 3 rows inside a message box using Pyqt5. How to do it?

I already have a code for showing message box which is as below:

```
def about_info():
    """
    Method for displaying framework version and links information to user
    """

    msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
    msg.setWindowTitle("About")
    msg.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(
        os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'gui_images', 'logo_icon.png'))))
    msg.setIconPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(
        os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'gui_images', 'splash_scr.png'))).scaledToHeight(
            80, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation))
    msg.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.RichText)
    msg.exec_()
```

What are the additional things I need to do to display a table within a message-box?

Comment: QMessageBox supports rich-text, so you can use markup to create simple tables and such-like. See the Qt Docs: [Supported HTML Subset](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html).

Comment: by table you mean `QTableView` or html table of text?

Comment: I mean QTableView

Comment: @user15861788 In that case, why bother with QMessageBox? Just create your own dialog with whatever widgets you need.

Comment: Actually I am working on a framework. In that , there is one help option in menu bar. After clicking on help option one drop-down list will appear. Inside that list there will be one button/option ,and after clicking on that button a pop-up should come which will have a table. ( Help --> abc --> pop-up with a table). So I was thinking to put a table inside a message-box.